# Multinomial Implementation for NetLogo

Tags: statistics, netlogo

Is there a function in NetLogo to draw samples from a multinomial distribution?

I need a function similar to numpy [multinomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html) function `numpy.random.multinomial(n, pvals, size=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want using the weighted draw functions in the bundled `rnd` extension, particularly rnd:weighted-n-of-with-repeats (see [documentation](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html))